# CLSAnalyticsController transmitPackagedSessionFragments generated NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I received a crash report *NSInternalInconsistencyException* in the *FABMultipartMimeStreamEncoder addFileData*, which was called by *CLSAnalyticsController transmitPackagedSessionFragments*.

I followed all the instructions about including Crashlytics into the project, but still received this crash report form one of the test users.

Stack info is below.

Thanks

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000184184f5c __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000198d7bf80 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000184184e2c +[NSException raise:format:]
3  Foundation                     0x0000000185073f3c -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
4  MyApp                         0x00000001001bab0c -[FABMultipartMimeStreamEncoder addFileData:fileName:mimeType:fieldName:]
5  MyApp                         0x00000001001bae14 -[FABMultipartMimeStreamEncoder addFile:fileName:mimeType:fieldName:]
6  MyApp                         0x00000001001a93ac __74-[CLSAnalyticsNetworkingClient requestForLogFilesAtURLs:toURL:withAPIKey:]_block_invoke
7  MyApp                         0x00000001001ba5f8 -[FABMultipartMimeStreamEncoder encode:]
8  MyApp                         0x00000001001ba274 +[FABMultipartMimeStreamEncoder populateRequest:withDataFromEncoder:]
9  MyApp                         0x00000001001a9268 -[CLSAnalyticsNetworkingClient requestForLogFilesAtURLs:toURL:withAPIKey:]
10 MyApp                         0x00000001001a8f70 -[CLSAnalyticsNetworkingClient transmitLogFilesAtURLs:toURL:withAPIKey:completionHandler:]
11 MyApp                         0x00000001001a6168 -[CLSAnalyticsController transmitNextPackagedSessionFragment:]
12 MyApp                         0x00000001001a656c __59-[CLSAnalyticsController transmitPackagedSessionFragments:]_block_invoke
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001995757b0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000199575770 _dispatch_client_callout
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019958175c _dispatch_queue_drain
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000199579274 _dispatch_queue_invoke
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019958362c _dispatch_root_queue_drain
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019958334c _dispatch_worker_thread3
19 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000199789478 _pthread_wqthread
20 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000199789028 start_wqthread
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todd from the Crashlytics team here. The issue you are seeing is related to a SIGABRT crash of Crashlytics. This means that we were either unable to unwind the Crash before the application crash terminated Crashlytics. You might have better luck troubleshooting this crash by upgrading to the most recent version of the SDK.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. It makes sense. Will continue troubleshooting with more recent SDK version.